# Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

Today, when I opened my ASP.net project in Visual Studio 2010 with Telerik ASP.net Ajax 2013 Q2 installed on it, I realized that when running, it gives a server error, with this error info:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies. Strong name
>   signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered
>   with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct
>   private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

I tried deleting ASP.net temporary files in Windows folder but it didn't help. Can you please tell me how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as I found is to remove all references to that assembly and adding it again to the project.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Not sure why it started happening in the first place